# Defining Method with Argument that Cannot be Implicitly Converted

Tags: scala

I tried to define a method that takes a single argument that must be of type `A` **without** implicit conversion.

```
scala> def f[A](x: A =:= A) = x
f: [A](x: =:=[A,A])=:=[A,A]
```

To illustrate my point, the following is not acceptable:

```
scala> implicit def stringToInt(x: String) = x.toInt
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
stringToInt: (x: String)Int

scala> def g(x: Int) = x
g: (x: Int)Int

scala> g("5")
res5: Int = 5
```

But, when I try to call `f`, I get an error:

```
scala> f(100)
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(100)
 required: =:=[?,?]
       f(100)
         ^
```

How can I correct `f`?

Comment: you didn't declare `f` to take a parameter of type `A`, you declared it to take a parameter of type `A =:= A`. This is asking for evidence that for some type A, it is the same type as A (which is always true).  You might have instead declared it as `def f[A](x: A)(implicit ev: A =:= A) = ev(x)` but this isn't going to do what you want. A is always the same type as A, so this isn't doing anything, and it will still allow the implicit conversion to happen, as would `def f[A,B](x: A)(implicit ev: B =:= A) = ev(x)` I'm not sure if what you are trying to do is possible

Comment: You could do something like this with a macro but I'd suggest not.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid implicit conversion?

Comment: @TravisBrown - why'd you suggest against using macros?

Comment: @Daenyth - check out https://github.com/non/spire/issues/508#issuecomment-132686815

Comment: @KevinMeredith Macros are a sharp tool, and if you're not careful with them it's easy to make your code very hard to reason about. There's not really any good way to represent "this function takes an `A` but not via an implicit conversion" in the type system.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by stew, your use of `=:=` is incorrect.

Here is a correct way to do what you tried to:

```
def g[A](x: A)(implicit e: A =:= Int) = x
```

The advantage (in your case) of declaring `g` like this (over the more obvious `def g(x: Int) = x`) is that the check that the argument is of type `A` is done last (through the lookup for an appropriate implicit value), after the `x`  parameter has already been type checked. And given that when type checking `x` there is no information at all on the exact expected type, implicit conversion cannot kick in:

```
scala> g("123")
<console>:13: error: Cannot prove that String =:= Int.
              g("123")
           ^
scala> g(123)
res1: Int = 123
```

However, note that (as already mentioned by Sascha Kolberg), the caller could still explicitly specify `A`, allowing the implicit conversions to apply:

```
scala> g[Int]("123")
res1: Int = 123

scala> g("123":Int)
res2: Int = 123
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what your problem with implicitly converted arguments is and my recommendation would be to make peace with that, but here is an option that might work for you:

You could use the type class pattern to define a type context:

```
trait TypeEvidence[A]

object TypeEvidence {
  implicit object IntEv extends TypeEvidence[Int]
  implicit object LongEv extends TypeEvidence[Long]
  implicit object FloatEv extends TypeEvidence[Float]
  implicit object DoubleEv extends TypeEvidence[Double]
}
```

You can then restrict function arguments to available contexts:

```
object Foo {
  def getValue[A : TypeEvidence](a: A): Int = 1
}
```

Now, this function will take only arguments for which the scala compiler finds an implicit type class that matches the context bound.

```
implicit def s2i(in: String): Int = Integer.parseInt(in)

Foo.getValue(100)           | -> 1
Foo.getValue("100")         | -> compile error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter
```

**NOTE: If you annotate the type though, the implicit conversion will still kick in.**

```
Foo.getValue[Int]("100")    | -> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a generic method with a single argument, it will *always* be called with the type of the argument without any implicit conversions, unless you specify the type explicitly

```
def foo[A](x: A): A = x
val x = foo(1) // will be of type Int
val y = foo[Long](1) // will use Int => Long conversion and be of type Long
```

If you have a method with ***two*** arguments, the situation is different. For the method below, numeric coercions will be done by the compiler, and the compiler will find a common type.

```
def same[A](x: A, y: A) = x == y
foo(1, 1L) // works. coercion from int to long
foo(1, spire.math.Rational(1)) // A will be inferred to Any
```

If you do not want to allow numeric coercions or Any, one way to do this is to keep the types separate but require evidence that they are the same, like so:

```
def same[A, B](x: A, y: B)(implicit ev: A =:= B) = x == y
```

This will only work if x and y are indeed of the same type, ignoring both coercions and implicit conversions:

```
scala> same(1, 1L)
<console>:15: error: Cannot prove that Int =:= Long.
       same(1, 1L)

scala> implicit def stringToInt(x: String) = x.toInt
    stringToInt: (x: String)Int
scala> same("1", 1)
<console>:16: error: Cannot prove that String =:= Int.
       same("1", 1)
       ^
```

This can be used to define an operator that does not allow coercions or implicit conversions:

```
scala> implicit class NoCoercionEq[T](val lhs: T) { def ===[U](rhs:U)(implicit ev: T =:= U) = lhs == rhs }
defined class NoCoercionEq

scala> 1 === 1
res9: Boolean = true

scala> 1L === 1
<console>:21: error: Cannot prove that Long =:= Int.
       1L === 1
          ^
```